# Is it possible to undo virsh undefine on a running VM?

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

I accidentally wrote the wrong command, as the VM is still running it is not yet removed. Is it possible to undo this action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the VM is still running you should be able to use `virsh dumpxml` to recover the running configuration.

```
virsh dumpxml <vm_name> > vm_name.xml && \
virsh define vm_name.xml
```

Otherwise you should restore from your backup.